# Unexpected packet read error ODP.net managed driver on Dev server - works on local IIS

Tags: .net, oracle, driver, managed

I have code using .Net 4.6, c# and running using
EF6
nuget package : 
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.1.24160719
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.12.1.2400

Code deployed on local IIS works fine, when deployed on dev server (IIS 7) getting attached [ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS5Yt.jpg). (Note I have deployed on other local iis also, it works )

Comment: have you gone to Oracle website and try to understand when this error occurs?

Comment: no doc found, this error used to come for previous versions, with nuget it does not require any installation. I have added entry in web.config to ignore gac policy and use this version of managed driver

Comment: I googled for it and it returned 45K results. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:424289000563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that we had below **product version** in GAC (it has same file version and public token)

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll 4.121.2.20150926 ODAC RELEASE 4

we are using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll 4.121.2.20160624 ODAC RELEASE 4 (nuget package)

When we replaced the dll with the new product version in GAC or removed the dll from GAC - our app start working